# How to pass a variable to a sed command in a csh script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, tcsh, csh

Unix & Sed noob here!

I have a requirement where I need to put a suffix **",waive"** in case a line in a report containing a matching string.The matching string is part of another file **"waive.txt"**. I am also trying to perform these operations on a copy of the main report.

## I am putting an example below

Here is how the report looks like:

```
i love apple_tart as a desert
banana is full of potassium and iron
there are so many helath benefits of apple eating 
the king of fruit is mango 
there are apple_pie of many variety
```

Here is how **waive.txt** looks like:

```
apple_pie
banana
```

This is my expeted output which I want in the same file :

```
i love apple_tart as a desert
banana is full of potassium and iron,waive
there are so many helath benefits of apple eating 
the king of fruit is mango 
there are apple_pie of many variety,waive
```

This is the script I tried but it is giving *Illegal variable name* **Error**

```
#!/bin/csh -f
if (-r fruits_bkup.txt) then
  rm fruits_bkup.txt
endif

yes|cp fruits.txt fruits_bkup.txt
foreach word ("`cat waiver.txt`")
  sed -i "/${word}/s/$/ ,waived/" fruits_bkup.txt 
end
```

If I replace the double quotes with a single quotes in the sed command, nothing happens to the report.

Thanks!

Was expecting:

```
i love apple_tart as a desert
banana is full of potassium and iron,waive
there are so many helath benefits of apple eating 
the king of fruit is mango 
there are apple_pie of many variety,waive
```

Got:
*Illegal variable name* **Error**

Comment: If you're new then please don't waste your time learning how to script with `csh`. It's full of really irritating edge cases that you will hit really quickly. Oh.. that you _have_ hit. Instead learn `sh`, `bash`, or possibly even `zsh`.

Comment: I don't want to work on csh, I have to work on csh because of the nature of work.

Comment: Do you have a manager telling you you need to write scripts in `csh`, or is it simply because your login shell is `csh`?  If it's the latter, then you need to be aware that there is no issue writing shell scripts for another shell than the shell you use for login shell. Writing a `/bin/sh` script would be possible, just like writing a Perl or Python script would be possible.

Comment: I am aware that I could switch shells but,  most of my work and relevant reports are generated on csh, so, for continuity, I am trying to do automation in csh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding the quirks of the `csh` shell, we may solve this with a single `awk` command (which you may put into a `csh` script if you so wish).  This also allows us to reduce the number of passes we need to make over the input file (we only need a single pass).

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR { query[++n] = $0; next } { for (i in query) if ($0 ~ query[i]) { $0 = $0 ",waive"; break } };1' waive.txt report.txt
```

The command first reads the lines of the first file, `waive.txt`, into the associative array `query`.  When we reach the second file, `report.txt`, we iterate over the patterns in `query` and test each against the current line.  If there is a match, we add `,waive` to the end of the line and terminate the loop.

At the end, the trailing `1` causes the (possibly modified) line to be outputted.

Note that this uses the text from the first file as regular expressions.  Would you want to do string comparisons instead, use `index(query[i],$0)` in place of `$0 ~ query[i]` in the code.

To write the result back to the original file, pipe the output to `sponge report.txt`, or redirect it to a new filename and then rename that new file to `report.txt`.

Comment: This works as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kausalananda A follow-up question:
If the string to be matched has special characters like [, ], /, \, &, $ etc then, how do we take care of this in our command?

Comment: @Aditya I mentioned that there is a way to do string comparisons rather than regular expression matches. You will have to make the tiny modification that I explain in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: Got it! thanks for pointing this out again.